# getting distinct mysql result of one field based on another field

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have this code:

```
select count(distinct affiliate_orders_id) as count
, sum(affiliate_value) as total
, sum(affiliate_payment) as payment 
from " . TABLE_AFFILIATE_SALES . " a 
    left join " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o on (a.affiliate_orders_id = o.orders_id)
where a.affiliate_orders_id = o.orders_id 
and o.orders_status >= " . AFFILIATE_PAYMENT_ORDER_MIN_STATUS . "
        ";

  $affiliate_sales_query= tep_db_query($affiliate_sales_raw);
  $affiliate_sales= tep_db_fetch_array($affiliate_sales_query);
```

So, $affiliate_sales['total'] = 128000 when in fact it should be 32000 becuase there are multiple affiliate_values and affiliate_orders_id.  The affilaite_values some have the same values so these cannot be distinct.  affilaite_orders_id have all unique values but there are multiple rows of this and needs to be distinct.  Then the affiliate_values has to sum up based on the distinct rows of affiliate_orders_id to get an accurate sum.

I'm trying to get the sum of all affiliate_values bused on how many distinct affiliate_orders_id are in the table.

Comment: what doesn't work? This should work as designed

Comment: i'm trying to get the sum of affiliate_values fields, but only based on the affiliate_orders_id distinct fields.  Right now "total" is pulling all totals from this field.

Comment: how do you decide which row to pull if there are multiple affiliate_orders_id ?

Comment: all distinct affiliate_orders_id rows.

Comment: so you mean if there's only one affiliate_orders_id is the whole table or if there are multiple id's with separate values? Please post some sample data.

Comment: i edited above.  hopefully that helps.  idk.  it's kind of hard to explain especially when there are other conditions going on in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update I think this will get you what you're looking for. You need to use a subQuery

```
SELECT COUNT(a) COUNT, SUM(av) total, SUM(ap) aptotal
FROM (
    SELECT affiliate_orders_id a, affiliate_value av, SUM(affiliate_payment) AS ap
from " . TABLE_AFFILIATE_SALES . " a 
    left join " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o on (a.affiliate_orders_id = o.orders_id
    GROUP BY affiliate_orders_id, affiliate_value)
where a.affiliate_orders_id = o.orders_id 
and o.orders_status >= " . AFFILIATE_PAYMENT_ORDER_MIN_STATUS . ") a
```

Now this leads to a bigger question. Are you missing a join condition in your tables? Typically you shouldn't have duplicate date returned in a query, so I would suggest double checking your query is joining properly first.

Comment: Ok, this is getting there.  I don't know how to include the other condition above for the sum(affiliate_payment) as payment.

Comment: should that be based off a distinct as well? or should that be calculated in the inner Query?

Comment: it's just calculating the sum straight up from all rows.

Comment: I used the original code you put up before and just setup a separate query for the affiliate_payment and it works fine that way.  So if you want to put the original code up you can.
    SELECT COUNT(a) count, SUM(av) total
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT affiliate_orders_id a, affiliate_value av
from " . TABLE_AFFILIATE_SALES . " a 
    left join " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o on (a.affiliate_orders_id = o.orders_id)
where a.affiliate_orders_id = o.orders_id 
and o.orders_status >= " . AFFILIATE_PAYMENT_ORDER_MIN_STATUS . ") a